# Converting data and using sed/awk

Tags: shell

I have a file which is provided below, Col1/Field 1 will always have duplicate data the rest of the fields may/may not but am not worried of other columns, all I need is if there is duplicate data it need to be printed with empty space for col1 and the values of Field 1 will be ordered so no values repeats further down the rows.

```
 COL1  | COL2 | COL3
----------------------
A1     | 98   | P
A1     | 98   | P
A1     | 98   | P
B1     | 98   | P
B1     | 98   | P
B1     | 98   | P
C1     | 98   | P
C1     | 98   | P
C1     | 98   | P
```

need to convert and the awk/sed need to be applied on col1 only 
(the output should look like below after awk/sed/cut is used)

```
 COL1  | COL2 | COL3
----------------------
A1     | 98   | P
       | 98   | P
       | 98   | P
B1     | 98   | P
       | 98   | P
       | 98   | P
C1     | 98   | P
       | 98   | P
       | 98   | P
```

awk '!x[$1]++' file <-- is removing whole line

awk/sed/cut anything is fine.
Wrote 50 lines of code , struck at last phase

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { c1 = $1 } c1 == prev { gsub(".", " ", $1) } { prev = c1; print }' file
 COL1  | COL2 | COL3
----------------------
A1     | 98   | P
       | 98   | P
       | 98   | P
B1     | 98   | P
       | 98   | P
       | 98   | P
C1     | 98   | P
       | 98   | P
       | 98   | P
```

The `awk` program reads `|`-delimited input data and writes `|`-delimited output data.

For each line in the input, it extracts the first column into `c1` and compares it to the previous first column, `prev`.  If they are the same, the value of the first column is overwritten by spaces (this is what the `gsub()` does, and it prevents the column width from changing). The recorded "previous first column" is then updated with the value of `c1` and the (possibly modified) line is printed.

Comment: What to do if I wish to do the same comparison with Col1 and Col2

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do same thing for 2 or more columns; I have added the same logic for needed columns but its becoming too lengthy; any other short/easy way to do same logic for Col1, Col2